# Changing the behaviour of view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for a project that is used by a variety of companies.

The default version of our software is up and running and works fine - however some of our customers want slightly different view files for their instance of the system.

Ideally what I would like to do is set a variable (for example VIEW_SUFFIX) and whenever a view file is loaded it would first check if there was a suffix version available if there was use that instead.

For example if the system had a standard view file called 'my_view.php' but one client had a VIEW_SUFFIX of 'client_1' - whenever I called $this->load->view('my_view') if the VIEW_SUFFIX was set it would first check if my_view_client_1 existed (and if it did use that) or if not use the default my_view.php.

I hope that my question is clear enough... If anyone has done this before or can think of a way to do it I would really appreciate it.

EDIT:
Ideally I would like a solution that works without me changing every place that I am calling the view files. Firstly because there are a few files that may want different client versions and also because the view files are called from a lot of controllers

Comment: This can be done by creating helper, or "`_render($param = "default_suffix")`" function [what I mean, create new `private function _render()` in either each controller or in `core` controler.

Comment: This could work - ideally I would like not to have to change all the places where the views are called however - so if there was some way of actually changing the way the $this->load->view functionality worked that would be ideal but this is definitely a step in the right direction :) Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement for which I created a helper function. Among other things, this function can check for a suffix before loading the specified view file. This function can check for the suffix and check if the file exists before loading it.

Unfortunately, the file checking logic would be a bit brittle. As an alternative, you can implement a `MY_Loader` class that will override the basic `CI_Loader` class.

Something like this in your `application/core/MY_Loader.php`:

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {
    protected function _ci_load($_ci_data)
    {
        // Copy paste code from CI with your modifications to check prefix.
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promsing - will look into this and let you know how it goes! Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do this

```
// some method of creating $client
// probably created at login
$_SESSION['client'] = 'client_1';

$client = (isset($_SESSION['client'])) ? $_SESSION['client'] : '';
$this->load->view("your_view{$client}", $data);
```

Comment: This is similar to Kyslik idea - storing the client in Session or in the config isn't a huge issue but this would still require me to edit every place that I am calling the view file...

I will try and make it more obvious in my original question but thankyou for your help :)